# How to pass Javascript variable as a parameter to MVC action method?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my tried example snippet

```
<body>
<span name="searchType" value="" id="spanSearchTypeFromQueryString" />
</body>

<script>
    var searchTypeFromQueryString = "ExampleSearch";
document.getElementById('spanSearchTypeFromQueryString').value = searchTypeFromQueryString[1];
</script>
```

I would like to pass the "**searchTypeFromQueryString**" variable to the action method through below snippet,

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller", new { searchType = searchTypeFromQueryString  })'>
</button>
```

Some of the examples are shown but not exactly what I want.

Edited with span ID

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is razor code which is parsed on the server before its sent to the browser. `searchTypeFromQueryString` is a javascript variable which does not even exist at that point (its not in scope). You can use `...href = '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller")' + '?searchType=' + searchTypeFromQueryString;`

Comment: Will it be read the value from the "searchTypeFromQueryString" variable directly from the script... @Stephen Muecke

Comment: I have edited my question please take a look once

Comment: Instead of `onclick="window.location.href`, call a function, and in the function declare the variable and then use `location.href = ....`